# Why was ambassador Sondland involved in Ukraine?

Tags: united-states, european-union, ukraine, trump-impeachment

Ambassador Sondland is ambassador to the EU. So why was he involved in Ukraine, a country that is not even in the EU? I understand that Ukraine is considering joining the EU but why was he so heavily involved there? Is that standard practice or highly irregular?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Yes, it's *"irregular"* (but *"not as outlandish as it could be"*)

Ambassador Taylor, in the opening statement of his public testimony before congress referred to the diplomatic channel of which Sondland was a part as the *irregular channel* (quoting from [the transcription by rev.com](https://www.rev.com/blog/impeachment-hearings-first-day-transcript-bill-taylor-george-kent-testimony-transcript)):

> At the same time, however, I encountered an irregular, informal channel of US policy-making with respect to Ukraine, unaccountable to Congress, a channel that included then-Special Envoy Kurt Volker, US Ambassador to the European Union Gordon Sondland, Secretary of Energy Rick Perry, White House Chief of Staff Mick Mulvaney, and, as I subsequently learned, Mr. Giuliani. I was clearly in the regular channel, but I was also in the irregular one to the extent that Ambassadors Volker and Sondland including me in certain conversations. Although this irregular channel was well-connected in Washington, it operated mostly outside of official State Department channels.

The counsel for the minority asked Ambassador Taylor about the irregular channel (see [this clip by PBS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sezBhcnSxI0)):

> I want to turn to the discussion of the irregular channel you describe. And, in fairness, this irregular channel of diplomacy, it's not as outlandish as, as it could be, is that correct?

And Ambassador Taylor replies, smiling:

> It is not as outlandish as it could be

And after a bit [the counsel for the minority asks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sezBhcnSxI0&feature=youtu.be&t=62):

> And the second member of the irregular channel is Ambassador Sondland, who is senate confirmed, ambassador to the EU, so his involvement here, while not necessarily part of his official duties to the EU, it certainly is not outlandish for him to be interested and engaged pursuant to the president or Secretary Pompeo's direction.

And Taylor replies:

> It's a little unusual for the US ambassador to the EU to play a role in Ukraine policy.

The counsel for the minority then [goes on to ask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sezBhcnSxI0&feature=youtu.be&t=96):

> And you know it might be irregular but it's certainly not outlandish.

Bill Taylor nods in reply.

Comment: Frankly, mr. Taylor's face and voice has put a clear italics on "could be" when he answered :)

Comment: Bill Taylor unconvincingly nods in reply while struggling to find the words to reply to the leading statement of counsel.

Comment: Reading transcript is not enough, you need to watch the video. It is very obvious that Taylor thinks "yes, sending Bozo the clown would be bit more outlandish, if you want that". But it is definitely not by the book, and Taylor is by-the-book guy.

Answer (score 30):

Ambassador Sondland is a hotel magnate who Donald Trump elevated to Ambassador to the EU as a reward for [large campaign contributions during Trump's 2016 presidential campaign](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2019/10/08/who-gordon-sondland-trump-ambassador-to-eu-impeachment-witness-key-player-ukraine/3867905002/). The actual Ambassador to Ukraine, Maria Yovanovitch, was a career diplomat and a longtime member of the US Foreign Service with a degree in Russian Studies from Princeton.

While Ambassador Sondland was not involved with anything but the [most rudimentary business](https://twitter.com/usambeu/status/973596753185378304?lang=en) involving Ukraine, he is currently indebted to Trump via the contribution-for-position quid pro quo they engaged in, and thus served as a much more trustworthy channel for Trump.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong but I doubt this is all down as hard fact anywhere so I'm guessing it isn't much more than conjecture on your part. Some evidence for things like "[he was] elevated to Ambassador to the EU as a reward for the large campaign contributions" and "when Trump requires illegal acts from his subordinates, he prefers to ask those people who owe him favors" would make this more of an answer than an opinion piece.

Comment: Is there evidence Sondland supported being involved in Ukraine policy? From what I read, he may not have been, e.g. his testimony, by [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-10-17/trump-donor-turned-envoy-faces-loyalty-test-in-impeachment-probe): *"“Inviting a foreign government to undertake investigations for the purpose of influencing an upcoming U.S. election would be wrong,” he said in the statement. “Withholding foreign aid in order to pressure a foreign government to take such steps would be wrong. I did not and would not ever participate in such undertakings.”"*

Comment: @LioElbammalf: It's been a longstanding observation that US ambassadors can be divided into career diplomats and donors. This is not new to Trump's presidency; it's accepted by Republicans and Democrats alike. I don't think there's a real need for evidence that Sondland is a donor instead of a career diplomat.

Comment: @MSalters but it's a step further to imply that the ambassador thus owes the president favors. One might say that by getting the ambassadorship the president and his donor are even and no more favors are owed. To imply that an ambassador, who has taken the oath of office would be more loyal to the president is rather bold, right?

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica: Agree. That's why I restricted my conclusion to the first paragraph. But since my comment, both paragraphs gained links so these comments are becoming obsolete.

Comment: @MSalters Well, that *Slate* link is subtitled "A Mafia expert explains why Trump feels so much like a mobster."  The *Washington Post* link is titled "Trump's creepy, autocratic obsession with autonomy".  They're **opinion** pieces that don't even pretend to be news articles.

Comment: @MSalters Neither of these links support that Sondland is considered owing a favor to Trump. It also doesn't work that way, the most leverage Trump has over Sondland (to my knowledge) is the ability to fire him, that is not enough to *"flip"* someone.

Comment: @JJ for Transparency and Monica: OTOH, if you've just paid a million dollars or so for a prestigious ambassadorship, are you likely to throw it away by going against the man who can fire you on a whim?

Comment: @MSalters Wow....I was not aware that American politics worked like that...just pay enough and you can have yourself some power with the backing of one of the largest economies? I imagine that comes in handy for business people with international dealings. I may well just be naïve and this happens everywhere but I'm surprised its an accepted thing.

Comment: @LioElbammalf To be fair to Sondland, he was Trump's second choice for the position. Luckily for Sondland, the other guy (Ted Malloch) was of the mold of Trump appointees that want to dissolve the group they're in charge of, and the EU wasn't a big fan. Oh, and Malloch also falsely claimed to have a knighthood, that his documentary was Emmy-nominated, that he had written for the NYT and Washington Post, held a professorship at Oxford, and had completed his doctoral program in less than three years.

Comment: @LioElbammalf Around 33% of ambassadors of the US are political donors rather than career diplomats. Under Trump it is higher than average at 45% https://text.npr.org/s.php?sId=771412641

Comment: @LioElbammalf -- In your first comment, changing the post to impute anything illegal would only make it more of an opinion piece--that's exactly what most of the Democrats in the House are contending but it's certainly *not* an empirical fact--at least, not at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The question itself asks the answerers to project interpretations onto a situation that none of us have been a part of and all of us have skewed interpretations for relative to the sources of information we derive our views from.

Is it uncommon that an Ambassador of another region was involved in another Ambassador's matters at the behest of the US President?  Yes.  Is it illegal?  No.  Was there potential reason to do so?  Yes, given the behavior of Maria Yovanovitch.

Understand that US Ambassadors work for the Executive branch of government (the President).  An Ambassador working counter to the agenda of the head of the Executive Branch, and very publicly at that, might be principled but certainly isn't appropriate.  Just as Gen. Petraeus was removed by Obama for publicly speaking out against the President, it is entirely legitimate for Trump to do the same.

Working with the US government for 20 years and in large corporations, it is not at all uncommon for someone who can be trusted to be put in an 'oversight' or 'dual-hatted' position to address a problematic institution--in this case, the Ukrainian team.

Comment: What behavior of Marie Yovanovitch?

Comment: Publicly disparaging her boss's policies.

Comment: What evidence have you to show that?

Comment: Have you been watching impeachment for the last 3 months?

Comment: What you're missing is that the evidence is irrelevant--if the President believes one of his employees is bad mouthing him, he has every right to fire them; even if the firing is based on bad information.  If you're unwilling to apply one iota of common sense, maybe "this website surely isn't for you?"

Comment: so if the president continually acts on bad information that many of his top advisors tell him is bunk you’re cool with that? Isn’t that... you know, dangerous? Second, common sense tells you of course POTUS can fire people at will, but when was that ever the bar? The point is whether or not the firing of a career, effective ambassador was warranted, and why POTUS acted on information about her from dubious actors with ulterior motives.

Comment: IMO, Trump has the emotional stability of a petulant child.  That doesn't change the fact that if his advisers fed him potentially bad information, that's his adviser's fault and not his.  To the point of the OP's post, he was getting information that she was trouble so he put people in place in an effort to assess the situation and minimize perceived damage and ultimately fired her.  Some recent historic perspective:  bad information got an Ambassador and staff killed in Libya and thousands killed in Iraq.  A potentially innocent's job is the lowest of concerns of recent presidential bungles.

Comment: the bad information wasn’t coming from his advisors though! It was coming from his personal lawyer and his associates, all of which either had business deals in Ukraine or clients in Ukraine under the scrutiny of the US Embassy in Ukraine’s anti-corruption efforts, often spearheaded by Yovanovitch. These were the precise conflict of interest issues raised to POTUS by his advisors and he ignored them claiming, “Ukraine tried to take me down.” He necessarily associates OUR foreign policy with his personal whims - precisely this makes him unfit for office.

Comment: Again, his ego is a problem and the people how know that seem to be using it against him.  There were facets of the Ukrainian government who were publicly against him in the 2016 election.  Remember, according to every public source prior to the night of election, Hilary was going to win by a landslide.  Trump's ego likely wanted to punish and/or get revenge for the perceived slights.  Childish emotional responses for a President? ...Sure, but unless the Democrats can prove high crimes, it doesn't make him unfit for anything, other than peoples' opinions.

Comment: those Ukrainians were “against him” because he suggested Russia was right to annex Crimea from Ukraine...? Are they not allowed to tell foreigners running for office which territory is rightly theirs and which isn’t? It’s the fact that he couldn’t help but personally usurp power of purse from Congress to leverage Ukraine to damage Joe Biden that he’s being impeached, as recently detailed by John Bolton, along with Sondland, Hill, Holmes, and Taylor.

Comment: Of course they can--and they get to deal with the fallout of working with the politician they prematurely disparaged because they likely thought he wasn't going to win.  Trump didn't damage Joe Biden, he's done that all on his own.  One of the most comical aspects about this whole debacle is that Joe Biden's on tape doing exactly what the Democrats initially accused Trump of in the first place.  And lets not spread misinformation.  The only thing the Ukrainian team proved in their testimonies is that they disagreed with Trump's decisions.  And John Bolton has  testified?  That's news to me.

Comment: ooof. I see. This is an educational platform. I’m not going to debate things like “they get to deal with the fallout... Trump didn’t damage Joe Biden...Joe Biden did what everyone’s accusing Trump of doing...the ‘Ukrainian’ team proved that they disagreed with Trump only.” These are easily all shown to be false and unless we can work with an established set of facts, then this conversation is not worth having on this website.

Comment: If you are that dogmatic about it, then you're obviously only getting the highlights from your spin news sources.  I challenge you to go back and watch on YouTube every member of Ukrainian team testimony and report back with what damning evidence they provided. Because so far the only argument you've supplied that even comes close to being a formal charge for impeachment is the chart that Donald Trump went after Biden as a political opponent.  However that only holds water if Biden isn't corrupt. And at this point, that's not looking so good for him.

Comment: oh no, I read every deposition and watched every live hearing. Lol.

Comment: Then it should be easy for you to find the examples in their testimonies that support your position--remember, this is an educational platform so please provide links to the times in the videos where they say what you claim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103768/discussion-between-coreyman317-and-thepip3r).

Comment: I find it much too hard to argue this well in the comments. I'm trying very hard to cite links to the sondland, holmes, taylor, morrison, etc testimonies, but its hard to tell which page I'm on on a web page. I suggest you ask an official question and I'll answer it with my argument.